# Finding generating function or closed formula for star and bar problem where order of distribution does not matters

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, generating-functions

I was thinking of star and bar problem with order of distribution does not matters. But before that let me state the star and bar problem where distribution order matters:

> **Problem 1. Star and bar problem where distribution order matters**
>   Number of ways to distribute $n$ indistinguishable balls to $r$ boys is $\binom{n+r-1}{r-1}$. This is same as the coefficient of $x^n$ in $(1+x+x^2+...)^r=\frac{1}{(1-x)^r}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{k+r-1}{r-1}x^k$. That is, we have to put $k=n$ in $\binom{k+r-1}{r-1}$ to get $\binom{n+r-1}{r-1}$.

Now I came to know that it is not possible to have closed formula for the same where distribution order does not matters.

But then I came across following problem:

> **Problem 2.** Use generating functions to determine the number of ways to insert tokens worth \$1, \$2, and \$5 into a vending machine to pay for an item that costs r dollars in both the cases when **(a)** the order in which the tokens are inserted does not matter and **(b)** when the order does matter.
>
> **Solution 2(a)**: The generating function given for case (a) that is when distribution order does not matter was: $(1+x+x^2+x^3+· · · )(1+x^2+x^4+x^6+· · · )(1+x^5+x^{10}+x^{15}+· · · )$

**Q1.** I am surprised to see that this looks same as $(1+x+x^2+...)^r$ in problem 1, but it says distribution order does not matters, while in problem 1 distribution order matters. While the solutions individually makes sense to me, I am not able to cleanly understand why orders are differently considered in them. Is it because in Problem 1, all $r$ series are same and hence they lead to consideration of distribution order, while in Problem 2, series are different and hence they lead to non-consideration of order?

> **Solution 2(b)**: The generating function given for Problem 2(b), that is when distribution order matters was: $1+(x+x^2+x^5 )+(x+x^2+x^5 )^2+⋯=\frac{1}{1-(x+x^2+x^5)}                                                                        =\frac{1}{1-x-x^2-x^5}
> $

Now I understand how this come up, but I am guessing

**Q2.** What could be problem-1 counterpart for this? I feel there is none since problem 1 itself talks about considering order. Am I right?

**Q3.** The difference between Problem 1 and Problem 2 is that in problem 1, all series are same and have 1 as a difference between successive powers of $x$, whereas in problem 2, all series are different and have different differences between their successive powers of $x$. Can we find closed formula or generating function for ("without considering distribution order")-counterpart for problem 1 using the logic behind generating functions of both "with and without considering distribution order" versions of problem 2?

**Addition**

**Q4.** I feel that we cannot have generating function for problem 1 with distribution order ignored. Whereas we have generating function for problem 2(a) (which consider distribution order), but here we dont have closed formula. Can we have this as a final conclusion? Or anymore insight can be drawn?

Comment: What do you mean when you say order matters in the first problem? The balls are indistinguishable.

Comment: @kccu The boys in the problem are distinguishable. For example, boy $A$ gets $2$, boy $B$ gets $1$ is not the same as boy $A$ gets $1$, boy $B$ gets $2$.

Comment: @kccu to elaborate with example what I mean by "distribution order matters", if $r=2$ and $n=4$ (distributing 4 indistinguishable balls to 2 boys), there are $\binom{4+2-1}{2-1}=5$ ways to do the distribution: {{0,4},{4,0},{1,3},{3,1},{2,2}}. But if the distribution order does not matters, there are just 3 ways:{{0,4},{1,3},{2,2}}. Note that in 1st case {0,4} & {4,0} are separately considered, while in 2nd case they are considered only once. Same for {1,3} and {3,1}....

Comment: ...This can be better viewed as finding number of "sets" {$e_1,e_2$} such that $e_1+e_2=4$, while when order matters, we find number of "vectors" {$e_1,e_2$} (assuming in the concept of vectors, order is implicitly considers).

Comment: I see what you mean. I think the difference is this: in question 1, the order of the *balls* does not matter, but the order of the boys does. In question 1, the order of the bills still does not matter, but there is only one vending machine, so it does not make sense to say the order of the vending machines does/does not matter.

Comment: If we want to say the order of the balls matters in problem 1, then the number of distributions is just $r^n$, because for each of the $n$ balls we have $r$ choices of who to distribute it to. I don't see right now how to get that answer from a generating function, but it should be possible.

Comment: I guess $r^n$ will happen when both balls and boys are distinguishable. Here, balls are indistinguishable. You may say that 1st ball will go to any of $r$ boys, 2nd ball goes to any of $r$ boys and so on. But there is no such distinction as 1st ball and 2nd ball and so on. Any ball can be very well $i$-th ball.